# Does using a third party(non-Apple) MagSafe 45W power adaptor cause power problems with MacBookAir

Tags: macbook-pro, power, magsafe

I had to replace my power adaptor of 2010 version MacBookAir with a third party power adaptor (because it was cheaper) a few months down the line I am having to force wake up my MacBookAir and worried that the third party adaptor may be slowly damaging internal power circuitary. Am I right to be worried?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be worried. Power adapters which have not been Apple certified can be shoddily constructed, have inferior components, and frequently lack safety mechanisms that prevent harm to your device and yourself. This article at [Macworld](http://www.macworld.co.uk/news/apple/are-cheap-iphone-chargers-safe-unofficial-apple-power-chargers-safety-tips-3460975/) about iPhone chargers shows some of the problems. This forum thread at [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-are-your-experiences-with-knockoff-macbook-chargers.1685721/) discusses MacBook chargers specifically.

You may save a few dollars getting a non-Apple branded charger, but if it damages your machine, you may just end up spending much more money in the end.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more : when it is cheap - there is a reason.... if you expect your mac to work for more than 5 years (like 10) then a new charger is a small amount to pay...